# how to get return value from exe and restart it

Tags: c#, mfc

**Scenario:** I have a MFC code  which call an exe created in C# (it is a windows form application)

**Need:**  I need that the exe would return a value when closed and on the basis of the return value the same exe will started again

psudocode

```
  int result = RunExe("exename", arguments)
  if(result == 1)
  {
     result =  RunExe("exename", arguments)
  }
```

do I have to put the if condition  in loop?

plz give me some suggestion.
1.How to return a value from exe
2. How to collect the return value
3. How to restart the exe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your C# EXE can return an int value like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static int Main() {
    return 5;
}
```

Your other app has to handle the return value like the others here has explained.

```
var proc = Process.Start("mycsharwinformapp.exe"):
proc.WaitForExit();

//If the code is 5 restart app!
if(proc.ExitCode==5) Process.Start("mycsharwinformapp.exe"):
```

Answer (score 3):

The following method should do the trick;

```
private static int RunProcess(string processName, string arguments)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

Then call it like so;

```
int returnCode;
do
{
    returnCode = RunProcess("...", "...");
}
while (returnCode == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [process.ExitCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) and create a new EXE which controls the exitvalue and starts the original EXE if needed, or you save the information in a file on the disk if its more than an integer so you can process it from the parent process (the new EXE you create).

Answer (score 0):

like O.D wrote, `Process.ExitCode` is the value you are looking for ...

to start the process you can use `Process.Start(string_path_to_exe,string_args)` which will return a Process object that represents the started process ... to wait until the process has ended use the `WaitForExit()` method of that object

see [Process Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)